# Need to return cursor and not command_cursor with aggregate()

Tags: mongodb, cursor, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I need to iterate an aggregate() result twice. However it is impossible to rewind the command_cursor returned by aggregate(). I tried to turn to True the option UseCursor of aggregate() but it always returns a command_cursor. Is there a way to do what I want?

The main problem is that I can't store every documents returned by aggregate() in a list... It crashes my application and freeze my VM after ~127000 documents

Comment: Try to achieve whatever you want to do in the first iteration bringing those many documents twice from mongodb will not be good.

Answer (score 0):

Simple execute the `aggregate` twice:

```
pipeline = [...]
for doc in collection.aggregate(pipeline):
    # do step 1 with your documents

for doc in collection.aggregate(pipeline):
    # do step 2 with your documents
```

This is, in fact, what `rewind` on a normal Cursor actually does: it simply executes the same query twice.